# Couldnt connect to node

Tags: mist

I had ran ethereum for some time for developing. I had upgrade to the latest Mist 0.8.10, Wallet 0.8.10 and geth 1.6.5 on Windows 10. after this, everything seems to break, everytime i start my mist it will shows "node connection error".

After i deleted everything from User\Appdata - mist, wallet, geth and reinstall mist again (without separately installing geth). it is working ok until i switch from main to testnet. the same problem occured.

anyone have experience to resolved this issue and switch from main to testnet seamlessly?

i have no problem running geth from command line before launching mist or wallet. It will sync all the blockchain when mist starts.

[image]

Comment: For me inside `C:\Users\<Your username>\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum Wallet\binaries\Geth\unpacked` there was a `geth.exe`. I runned it as a administrator then everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Run mist.exe as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that geth is running?  The "node" that mist can't connect to is (I assume) a geth node on your computer.  If geth isn't running, then mist can't "connect to node" and you would get an error.

Comment: it is before i manually launched geth. if i ran geth in command line, this problem will go away. If i run geth in command line, i cannot switch between main and testnet from gui

Comment: Well you *must* have geth running or mist will not run.  I think the error about the "node" is telling you that you have to have your node (ie - geth) running in order to connect.  As far as switching between main and testnets, I don't know how to do that in Mist but that is a separate issue from the node error.

Answer (score 0):

I had deleted the mist browser again and used the zipped version instead of installer version. The problem goes away..

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the "Couldn't connect to node? See the logs for more:" error. When I ran Geth, it was stuck on "Starting P2P networking" and could not connect.

What worked for me was installing Geth, copying the Geth shortcut, and adding `--nat=none`.

```
"C:\Program Files\Geth\geth.exe" --fast --nat=none
```

Afterwards, open the Geth shortcut and make sure that it connects and stays running before opening Mist.

Download Geth here: https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

My sollution was to use "Ethereum wallet" (zip version) instead of "Mist".

(No one sollution described above worked for me)